# Effective Shopdesign (with ModelBinders?)

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0, razor, modelbinders

I´m planing a shopsystem. I want to sell different lamps. For that reason I have created a `basemodelclass` with properties which every lamp has and inherit from that class to special lampmodels. Now I want a controller to create productoffers but how can i do this? Do i need for every lampmodel a controller / view or is there a way to have one controller/view that can create me all kind of lamp?

I have read about **'ModelBinders'** and think this could be a solution but I have no idea how this could work. A small example would be nice :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have solved it and posted it in another question: [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6337246/how-to-convert-a-http-request-into-the-right-object)